# toggle pictures by hovering ul li

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover

I need it to be a javascript solution only please. Please refer to **[this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2qz2srqs/9)**.

The goal is to hover the dots on the right bottom corner and swap the images accordingly. But what it does now is showing a blank page when hovering, and the whole `ul` becomes vertical and goes to top left corner. What did I do wrong here???

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">  
        <section id="contentWrapper">   
                <div id="resistorContent" class="content">
                    <section id="resistorDetail1"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic1.jpg"></section>
                    <section id="resistorDetail2"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic2.jpg"></section>
                    <section id="resistorDetail3"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic3.jpg"></section>
                    <section id="resistorDetail4"><img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic4.jpg"></section>
                    <ul>
                        <li onMouseOver="showDetail(resistorDetail1)"></li>
                        <li onMouseOver="showDetail(resistorDetail2)"></li>
                        <li onMouseOver="showDetail(resistorDetail3)"></li>
                        <li onMouseOver="showDetail(resistorDetail4)"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var children = document.querySelectorAll('.content > section[id]')
                    function showDetail(target){
                        for (var i = 0, child; child = children[i]; i++) {
                        child.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
                    }
                </script>
```

POSSIBLE COLLIDING CSS ?:

```
.content section:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I updated your demo with a version that fits in the display panel a bit better.

Comment: And again to load the script in the head.

Comment: And one more time to fix a duplicate ID that was causing an error.

Comment: @isherwood Instead of updating what the OP wrote, simply make your own version and create a new answer. If you update the original post with fixed code, then it's not really a question anymore.

Comment: I don't believe that the things I fixed were the primary issue raised by the question. I made the edits I did to focus attention where it was due.

Comment: But the problem with changing the original code is that current answers now reference old code, code that isn't present anymore. So by changing anything but the formatting of the SO post, you're not helping, just hindering proper problem solving.

Comment: Opinions vary. Feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2qz2srqs/3/

## Reason

Your code was very close, but it had a few minor issues.

The first was a copy-paste error, you had two elements with the id of `resistorDetail3`.

Second, your syntax for the `onmouseover` event was incorrect. Prefix any javascript with `javascript:` and ensure it has proper syntax.

Third, your `showDetail` method expected a string `id` of the element to show. In your `onmouseover` declaration you had `showDetail(resistorDetail1)` instead of `showDetail('resistorDetail1')`.

Finally, when you javascript is referenced in the HTML, you need to make sure you load the javascript first. Just by taking a look at the developer's console you could see that it through an error `"showDetail is not defined.`. I switched it to `No wrap - in <body>` and it worked fine.

**BUT** I highly recommend against directly referencing javascript from your HTML. Instead, load the HTML first and then use the DOM ready event of javascript to bind your events. That will increase your load time and make it easier to switch to something like jQuery/Zepto if needed.

## Full Code

### HTML

```
<section id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="resistorContent" class="content">
        <section id="resistorDetail1">
            <img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic1.jpg" />
        </section>
        <section id="resistorDetail2">
            <img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic2.jpg" />
        </section>
        <section id="resistorDetail3">
            <img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic3.jpg" />
        </section>
        <section id="resistorDetail4">
            <img src="http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/pic4.jpg" />
        </section>
        <ul>
            <li onmouseover="javascript: showDetail('resistorDetail1')"></li>
            <li onmouseover="javascript: showDetail('resistorDetail2')"></li>
            <li onmouseover="javascript: showDetail('resistorDetail3')"></li>
            <li onmouseover="javascript: showDetail('resistorDetail4')"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

### JS

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.content > section[id]');

function showDetail(target) {
    for (var i = 0, child; child = children[i]; i++) {
        child.style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}
```

### CSS

```
(unchanged)
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. I appreciate your knowledge and patience

Answer (score 1):

Here's another working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/2qz2srqs/4/

The issue was a couple things.

1. You were passing undefined vars into your `onmouseover` attributes. You wanted strings (I quoted them)
2. In JSFiddle, you don't automatically get the window scope, so you have to assign a function as a property of a window if you want to be able to hit it with an event attribute.